# Network Switch Help for Lan Party

Tags: networking, router, lan, streaming, gaming

I am having 5 friends over for a gaming weekend/event thing. I was wondering if the switch I bought is good enough to handle this kind of traffic and whatnot. Should I keep the amount of connections going through the switch to a minimum? [This is what I bought.](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00002EQCW/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) My Ip connection is 50/10 so would it matter if it bottlenecks? If I were to stream from my PC should I connect straight to the router?

I have the means to return this switch and buy a better one. But this event is costing a bunch already and I am trying to save cash where I can. So in total, I have 4 ports on my router and 5 ports on the switch. So 7 total ports available for connecting.

Games likely to play:

1. Overwatch
2. Rocket League
3. Call of Duty
4. TableTop Simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That switch is more than capable of handling the load of 5 people for gaming.